# Monotouch Custon UIPicker get selected item

Tags: ios6, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, xamarin

This is my picker model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Mobile.iOS
{
    public class PickerDataModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

        public List<string> Items
        {
            get { return this._items;} 
            set { this._items = value;}
        }
        List<string> _items = new List<string>();

        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return this._items[this._selectedIndex]; }
        }
        protected int _selectedIndex = 0;

        public PickerDataModel()
        {   
        }

        public override int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, int component)
        {
            return this._items.Count;
        }

        public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
        {
            return this._items[row];
        }

        public override int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
        {
            this._selectedIndex = row;
            if (this.ValueChanged != null)
            {
                this.ValueChanged (this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create an action sheet to show the UIPicker like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Mobile.iOS
{
    public class ActionSheetChildAgePicker
    {
        #region -= declarations =-

        UIActionSheet actionSheet;
        UIButton doneButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        UIView owner;
        UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel ();

        #endregion

        #region -= properties =-
        public UIPickerView AgePicker
        {
            get { return agePicker; }
            set { agePicker = value; }
        }
        //create agepicker
        UIPickerView agePicker = new UIPickerView();
        /// <summary>
        /// The title that shows up for the date picker
        /// </summary>
        public string Title
        {
            get { return titleLabel.Text; }
            set { titleLabel.Text = value; }
        }

#endregion

        #region -= constructor =-

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ActionSheetChildAgePicker (UIView owner)
        {
            // save our uiview owner
            this.owner = owner;

            // configure the title label
            titleLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            titleLabel.TextColor = UIColor.LightTextColor;
            titleLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (18);

            // configure the done button
            doneButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle ("ZurfersMovil-LoginBar-SignButton.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            doneButton.SetTitleColor(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
            doneButton.SetTitle ("done", UIControlState.Normal);
            doneButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { actionSheet.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (0, true); };

            // create + configure the action sheet
            actionSheet = new UIActionSheet () { Style = UIActionSheetStyle.BlackTranslucent };
            actionSheet.Clicked += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine ("Clicked on item {0}", e.ButtonIndex); };



            //Set picker Model and items
            PickerDataModel agePickerDataModel = new PickerDataModel();
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("<2");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("3");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("4");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("5");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("6");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("7");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("8");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("9");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("10");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("11");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("12");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("13");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("14");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("15");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("16");
            agePickerDataModel.Items.Add("17");
            agePicker.Source = agePickerDataModel;
            agePicker.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            agePicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;


            // add our controls to the action sheet
            //actionSheet.AddSubview (datePicker);
            actionSheet.AddSubview(AgePicker);
            actionSheet.AddSubview (titleLabel);
            actionSheet.AddSubview (doneButton);
        }

#endregion

        #region -= public methods =-

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the action sheet picker from the view that was set as the owner.
        /// </summary>
        public void Show ()
        {
            // declare vars
            float titleBarHeight = 40;
            SizeF doneButtonSize = new SizeF (71, 30);
            SizeF actionSheetSize = new SizeF(owner.Frame.Width, agePicker.Frame.Height + titleBarHeight);
            RectangleF actionSheetFrame = new RectangleF (0, owner.Frame.Height - actionSheetSize.Height
                                                          , actionSheetSize.Width, actionSheetSize.Height);

            // show the action sheet and add the controls to it
            actionSheet.ShowInView (owner);

            // resize the action sheet to fit our other stuff
            actionSheet.Frame = actionSheetFrame;

            // move our picker to be at the bottom of the actionsheet (view coords are relative to the action sheet)
            agePicker.Frame = new RectangleF(agePicker.Frame.X, titleBarHeight, agePicker.Frame.Width, agePicker.Frame.Height);

            // move our label to the top of the action sheet
            titleLabel.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 4, owner.Frame.Width - 100, 35);

            // move our button
            doneButton.Frame = new RectangleF (actionSheetSize.Width - doneButtonSize.Width - 10, 7, doneButtonSize.Width, doneButtonSize.Height);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dismisses the action sheet date picker
        /// </summary>
        public void Hide (bool animated)
        {
            actionSheet.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (0, animated);
        }

        #endregion  
    }
}
```

Now on my view controller I trying to get the item selected like this but it doesn't work becuase I don't have a ValueChanged method.

```
actionSheetChildAgePicker.AgePicker.ValueChanged += (s, e) => {
                this.txtAge1Room1 = f.ToString ((s as UIPickerView).Select(1,0,true));
            };
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In ActionSheetChildAgePicker expose your agePickerDataModel and make it public.

I would also make your UIButton doneButton public as well in ActionSheetChildAgePicker..

```
    public UIButton doneButton = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
```

comment out the button Event in ActionSheetChildAgePicker so we can handle it in the view controller...

```
    doneButton.SetTitleColor(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
    doneButton.SetTitle ("done", UIControlState.Normal);
    //doneButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { actionSheet.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex    (0, true); };
```

Then in your view controller you can do something like this

```
  actionSheetChildAgePicker.doneButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { 
  string sPickedAge = actionSheetChildAgePicker.agePickerDataModel.SelectedItem;
  actionSheetChildAgePicker.Hide(true);
                    };
```